# How to put an image as a background of a button?

Tags: swiftui

For example, I was given this image to be used as a background for a button in Swiftui

https://imgur.com/a/rrUivhF

```
Button(action: action) {
            ZStack {
                Image("yellow")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                
                Text(text).padding()
            }
        }
```

For some reason the button becomes really big. I just want the shape of the background to be big enough to wrap around the text. How to do that?

I have also tried using background, same problem

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    Button(action: {}, label: {
        Text("Button hi how are you how are you")
            .padding()
    })

    .background {
        Image("yellow")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ZStack` doesn't work because a `ZStack` allows a `resizable` image to resize to as large as it wants.

While there may be a way for this to work with `ZStack`, I recommend using `background` instead. That is semantically what your image is, and `background` doesn't allow a `resizable` image to expand indefinitely, unlike `ZStack`.

Your attempt with `background` doesn't work because you added `scaledToFill`, which maintains the image's aspect ratio. A long button title makes the image wider, but also makes it taller. If you just remove `scaledToFill`, the image only gets wider.

[image]

Note that now the rounded rectangle gets stretched to a rather weird shape. If this is undesirable, pass the `capInsets` parameter to `resizable` to specify what parts of the image to *not* stretch. You only want it to stretch the inner yellow rectangle, and not the rounded bits on the outside.

From my eyeballing, it seems like the top, bottom, leading, and trailing 10 pixels of the image make up the "roundedness", so you can do:

```
Button {} label: {
    Text("Button hi how are you how are you")
        .padding()
}
.background {
    Image("yellow")
        .resizable(capInsets: .init(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10))
}
```

[image]

That said, if the image is just a yellow rounded rectangle, you can just write that in code instead of using an image, which can get pixelated when you stretch it.

```
.background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).fill(.yellow))
// or
.background(.yellow)
.cornerRadius(10)
```

Comment: An amazing answer. But can you explain what the stretching logic is such that it will lead to that weird shape without Insets?

Comment: @erotsppa See [this section of the `UIImage` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage#1658362). They used a very good image to illustrate this.

Comment: @erotsppa You can also set the image caps in the asset catalog by using the "slicing" feature. Go to Editor -> Show Slicing and click start slicing.